# Django permissions checks at urlconf level?

Tags: django, url, permissions, django-class-based-views

I've got a django app that has it's own urlconf included into the main one.  Every page in this app is protected by a separate set of perms not granted to normal users.  Think employees work view as opposed to users' profiles etc.

I'm using classed based views, so right now I've got the landing view's dispatch() checking perms, but with this method I'm going to have to do that for every view.  That just isn't DRY.

So my options as I see them are:

- Create a mixin that specifically checks for this permission
- manually check using dispatch() in each view
- Somehow check at the url level

Is there any way to set a permission requirement on the entire url inclusion? They all currently have login_required() on.

Answer (score 1):

Easy!

```
from django.contrib.auth.decorators import login_required

urlpatterns = patterns('',
    url(r'^foo/', login_required(include('foo.urls'))),
)
```

**Update**

You want to check user permissions, not user authentication. Easy too:

```
from django.contrib.auth.decorators import user_passes_test

urlpatterns = patterns('',
    url(r'^foo/', user_passes_test(lambda u: u.has_perm('perm'))(include('foo.urls'))),
)
```

Comment: Going to try that in a bit.  Does this throw 403 if it fails?

Comment: No, it redirects to LOGIN_URL. If you want it to redirect to another url, pass it after the lambda function.

Comment: You could use [permission_required](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.5/topics/auth/default/#django.contrib.auth.decorators.permission_required) instead of user_passes_test. You can configure that function to raise an exception instead of redirect to LOGIN_URL.

Comment: I tried this, but now my login view won't find the included views with revserse()