# How to check user is authorised or not in urls.py?

Tags: python, django

I'm using a library for creating several calls in the front end but I have a problem. The library does not have authenticated user control, which is a severe problem, and also I cannot change the library for some reason.

Is there a way to control the user login in urls.py?

**urls.py**

```
from drf_auto_endpoint.router import router
...
    path('api/v1/', include(router.urls)),
```

Comment: I think [the answer to your question is here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23941518/django-permissions-checks-at-urlconf-level#23941831).

Answer (score 0):

If you want to check if user is_authenticated or not in `urls.py`, you can use `login_required` function:

```py
from django.contrib.auth.decorators import login_required

path('api/v1/', login_required(include(router.urls))),
```

You can see some examples in [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5722811/how-do-i-use-the-the-login-required-decorator-in-my-url)

Comment: I'm getting Page not found (404) error with this

Comment: Did you check the shared link ? @edche

Comment: Yes I checked it

Comment: Are you sure that your `router.urls` are OK ? @edche

Comment: Yes when I remove login_required it's working

Comment: Pass `login_url` param to it and check: `login_required(include(router.urls), login_url="sth")` @edche